# TypeScript Generic Method Signature in Interface

Tags: generics, typescript

I am trying to define an interface with a few methods, and I would like one of the methods to be generic.

It is a `filterUnique` method, so it should be able to filter lists of numbers, strings, etc.

the following does not compile for me:

```
export interface IGenericServices {
    filterUnique(array: Array<T>): Array<T>;
}
```

Is there a way to make this compile, or am I making a conceptual mistake somewhere here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `T` type isn't defined yet. It needs to be added to the method as a type variable like:

```
filterUnique<T>(array: Array<T>): Array<T>;
```

Or added to the interface like:

```
export interface IGenericServices<T> {
    filterUnique(array: Array<T>): Array<T>;
}
```

Comment: In case it helps others, you can also define a generic for the *method* of an interface without requiring the generic for the *entire* interface: 

`interface MyInterface { method: <T>(arg: T): T; }`

Comment: @williaster If you would post that as an answer you would get my upvote, because that syntax was exactly what I was looking for when I landed on this page. Thanks! Small correction, change `:` to `=>`: `<T>(arg: T) => T;`

Answer (score 0):

Making [williaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704645/typescript-generic-method-signature-in-interface#comment112671401_32704797) an answer as it also covers what many people are seeking for this question.

> You can also define a generic for the method of an interface without requiring the generic for the entire interface:
>
> ```js
> interface MyInterface {
>   method: <T>(arg: T) => T;
> }
> ```